# HTML UI: What do you call two side by side lists that can add from one to the other?

Tags: jquery, html, list, filtering

[image: Example of UI I want to accomplish]
So we want to incorporate this functionality into our web app (Ruby on Rails / jQuery). Does anyone know what you'd call this? Bonus: Is there something out there that accomplishes the filtering AND moving items from one list to the other? Thanks in advance. I don't even know what to google to find more info on this, otherwise, I wouldn't be asking!

Comment: This question may be better suited to ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a clear name for it, but "[jquery multiselect.js](http://loudev.com/)" looks like something you are looking for. It is also possible to make the fields searchable.